# KBC to ETH transaction

Tags: transactions, etherscan

I withdrew KBC from my HitBTC account to my countries local crypto app LUNO which only supports ETH.
This transaction was sucssesfull however I can not retrieve it from my Luno account. They say it cannot be recieved.
Is there anyway to reverse it or get this crypto back

Answer (score 1):

KBC appears to be a token, via a smart contract, on the Ethereum blockchain.

If LUNO only supports ETH and you sent KBC to your LUNO account, that means their development team has not built the tools necessary to interact with ERC20 or like tokens. As in, your KBC balance will not how in their own systems.

Your KBC balance will continue to exist on the account you sent it to.

There is **no way** to reverse this with generic ERC20 tokens.

Your only hope at this point, from what I know, is to continue contacting support and see if they have a way to manually transfer those coins. This won't be easy as you're going to prove that you owned them in the first place as well as convince them to go through that effort.

In the future, I would take your time and take the proper precautions before sending tokens between 3rd party exchanges and 3rd party wallets. You're at their mercy.